# Marionette Best Practices: Collection as an attribute

Tags: events, collections, attributes, models, marionette

I have a user which is a Marionette Model.
A user has a list of clients which I want to represent as a Collection.
A user has a currentClient which is a reference to one of the models in the clients Collection.

My question is, does it make sense to have the Collection of clients as an attribute of user or should I create a requestor for the client list, passing the user?

If it makes sense I'd rather keep clients as an attribute as I want to register events to alter other Views based on the data inside the currentClient when currentClient is reassigned.  I don't know if this is the optimal way to handle this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a best practice, I would say trying to keep models "flat" will prevent headaches later on, especially when it comes to operations like `toJSON` (the nested collection will only become an array of Backbone models). Changes inside vanilla objects and arrays nested in models cannot be tied to Backbone's eventing system easily.

Your description lists many "has-a" and "has-many" relationships. What's "optimal" very much depends on you app's architecture. Thankfully, Backbone has a pretty good plugin community to help you shape how you want your app to behave:

[Backbone.Relational](http://backbonerelational.org/) is a popular plugin for handling these types of relationships. It abstracts the nested collection use case with a bit of configuration.

Comment: Very sorry for the delay, I was pulled away from this project quite suddenly and had not reviewed your answer. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @KevinB, no worries. I have worked on a few Backbone/Marionette apps since I gave my answer, and have taken both approaches, plugin managed, and hand-managed relationships. In fact, I had a very similar use case where a Parent model had an attribute that referenced the ID of one of its Children. Ultimately, that was the easiest way to handle it on the front end and persist it to a database.